# How to create a ring buffer using an endless gstreamer video stream

Tags: bash, stream, buffer, gstreamer

I'm creating an application in which a camera module is read using an embedded linux development board (phyBOARD). The camera provides a continuous stream of data at 25 frames per second and each frame is saved onto the board's RAM (/tmp directory). To control and read out the camera module I'm using gstreamer commands in a bash script; Gstreamer version 1.14.1 combined with embedded linux yocto.

From this stream I want to grab a single frame which then is processed by an openCV algorithm. This frame is only grabbed appr. 2 times a second, so not all of the 25 frames are being used. However, the 25 frames per second are mandatory because each frame is displayed to the user using a separate script.

Below I have provided the current code which is used to start the stream and save all its frames into a single jpg file:

```
STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE=-1
FILE_LOCATION=/tmp/cameraStreamResults
FRAME_RATE=25/1
FILE_NAME=streamImage.jpg

mkdir -p $FILE_LOCATION # Create new directory if not available

gst-launch-1.0 \
    v4l2src num-buffers=$STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE device=$IPU1_CSI0_DEVICE ! \
    video/x-$COL_FORMAT$FRAME_SIZE,framerate=$FRAME_RATE ! \
    videoconvert ! \
    jpegenc ! \
    multifilesink location=$FILE_LOCATION/$FILE_NAME &
```

Because the stream is capturing at 25 frames a second into a single jpg image there's a high possibility that the file is corrupted when read. This is caused by the fact that the program tries to edit and read the same file at the same time.

I figured I could use some sort of ring buffer. This buffer forces the stream to save its frames into 10 different variables. Frame 1 goes into picture1.jpg, frame 2 in picture2.jpg and so on. After the 10th frame the next frame should be stored in picture1.jpg. This solution should provide a small delay between reading and changing the file and in theory reduces the possibility of a corrupted picture.

Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with bash and I'm not aware on how I could add this functionality to the gstreamer stream. Is it possible to add multiple instances under the gst-launch-1.0 command? Or should I use a different script which is connected to the gstream using a pipe connection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way to avoid opening too early is to just wait for the next frame file to be created before processing the current frame file? Perhaps if there is some internal concurrency on the hardware, you need to wait for 2 frames to be written.

Comment: Hi Gem, this solution sounds pretty reasonable. But I'm not sure how to achieve a delay in the gstream command. To me it looks like a stream which just keeps going. Do you know how one can add a delay which waits before writing to the file? Or should this operation be executed in the script which reads the image?

Comment: I don't know gstreamer at all, so I am looking at it only as a bash problem, sorry. From bash you could perhaps move each frame to another folder only when the next/next+1 frame file exists, that way this second folder only ever shows complete frames, but that may not be great if the images are on a hardware hosted virtual folder.

Answer (score 1):

videorate is for this kind of job.

```
... ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/2 ! jpegenc ! ...
```

Gstreamer website has details and examples.
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videorate/index.html?gi-language=c